# How to prevent service from quitting in Android?

Tags: android

My service is using the ActivityRecognition API and a LocationListener to save the current location when a user stops driving.

It works fine while the app is open, but I'm having no luck keeping detection going after the app has closed.

This is the service to detect activity & save location:

```
public class ActivityRecognitionService extends IntentService implements LocationListener {

    public Location currentBestLocation;
    private LocationManager locationManager ;
    private String provider;

    private String TAG = this.getClass().getSimpleName();
    public ActivityRecognitionService() {
        super("ActivityRecognitionService");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        try {
            locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
            provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
            if (provider != null && !provider.equals("")) {
                Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 1000, 1, this);

                if (location != null)
                    onLocationChanged(location);
                else
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Location can't be retrieved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "No Provider Found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } catch(SecurityException e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Enable location permissions from settings", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        ActivityRecognitionResult result = ActivityRecognitionResult.extractResult(intent);
        Log.i(TAG, "Detected activity being called... ");

        // Get the list of the probable activities associated with the current state of the
        // device. Each activity is associated with a confidence level, which is an int between
        // 0 and 100.
        ArrayList<DetectedActivity> detectedActivities = (ArrayList) result.getProbableActivities();

        for (final DetectedActivity activity : detectedActivities) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Detected activity: " +  getActivityString(activity.getType()) + ", " + activity.getConfidence());

            if(activity.getConfidence() < 60)
                continue;

            logActivity(getActivityString(activity.getType()), activity.getConfidence());

            List<UserActivity> userActivities = UserActivity.listAll(UserActivity.class);
            if(!userActivities.isEmpty()) {
                UserActivity last = userActivities.get(userActivities.size() - 1);
                if(last.activity.equals("in vehicle") && activity.getType() != DetectedActivity.IN_VEHICLE) {
                    logParking();
                }
            }


        }
    }



    private void logActivity(String type, int confidence) {
        UserActivity ua = new UserActivity(type, confidence, (System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L));
        ua.save();
    }

    private void logParking() {
        Location l = currentBestLocation;
        CarLocation cl = new CarLocation(l.getLongitude(), l.getLatitude(), (System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L));
        cl.save();
    }

    static String getActivityString( int detectedActivityType) {
        switch(detectedActivityType) {
            case DetectedActivity.IN_VEHICLE:
                return "in vehicle";
            case DetectedActivity.ON_BICYCLE:
                return "on bicycle";
            case DetectedActivity.ON_FOOT:
                return "on foot";
            case DetectedActivity.RUNNING:
                return "running";
            case DetectedActivity.STILL:
                return "still";
            case DetectedActivity.TILTING:
                return "tilting";
            case DetectedActivity.UNKNOWN:
                return "unknown";
            case DetectedActivity.WALKING:
                return "walking";
            default:
                return "unknown";
        }
    }

    /**
     * Only replaces current location if this reading is
     * more likely to be accurate
     * @param location
     * @return
     */
    private static final int TWO_MINUTES = 1000 * 60 * 2;
    protected boolean isBetterLocation(Location location) {
        if (currentBestLocation == null) {
            // A new location is always better than no location
            return true;
        }

        // Check whether the new location fix is newer or older
        long timeDelta = location.getTime() - currentBestLocation.getTime();
        boolean isSignificantlyNewer = timeDelta > TWO_MINUTES;
        boolean isSignificantlyOlder = timeDelta < -TWO_MINUTES;
        boolean isNewer = timeDelta > 0;

        // If it's been more than two minutes since the current location, use the new location
        // because the user has likely moved
        if (isSignificantlyNewer) {
            return true;
            // If the new location is more than two minutes older, it must be worse
        } else if (isSignificantlyOlder) {
            return false;
        }

        // Check whether the new location fix is more or less accurate
        int accuracyDelta = (int) (location.getAccuracy() - currentBestLocation.getAccuracy());
        boolean isLessAccurate = accuracyDelta > 0;
        boolean isMoreAccurate = accuracyDelta < 0;
        boolean isSignificantlyLessAccurate = accuracyDelta > 200;

        // Check if the old and new location are from the same provider
        boolean isFromSameProvider = isSameProvider(location.getProvider(),
                currentBestLocation.getProvider());

        // Determine location quality using a combination of timeliness and accuracy
        if (isMoreAccurate) {
            return true;
        } else if (isNewer && !isLessAccurate) {
            return true;
        } else if (isNewer && !isSignificantlyLessAccurate && isFromSameProvider) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private boolean isSameProvider(String provider1, String provider2) {
        if (provider1 == null) {
            return provider2 == null;
        }
        return provider1.equals(provider2);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        if(isBetterLocation(location)) {
            currentBestLocation = location;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        permissionsCheck();
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }

    public void permissionsCheck() {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                ) {

            // Check Permissions Now
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                    LocationScene.mActivity,
                    new String[] { Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION },
                    0);
        }
    }

}
```

This service is being used to start the above service and keep it running:

```
public class BackgroundDetectedActivitiesService extends Service {
    private static final String TAG = BackgroundDetectedActivitiesService.class.getSimpleName();
    IBinder mBinder = new BackgroundDetectedActivitiesService.LocalBinder();
    private Intent mIntentService;
    private PendingIntent mPendingIntent;
    private ActivityRecognitionClient mActivityRecognitionClient;

    public BackgroundDetectedActivitiesService() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

        super.onCreate();

        mActivityRecognitionClient = new ActivityRecognitionClient(this);
        mIntentService = new Intent(this, uk.co.appoly.wheres_my_car.services.ActivityRecognitionService.class);
        mPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 1, mIntentService, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        requestActivityUpdatesButtonHandler();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mBinder;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    public void requestActivityUpdatesButtonHandler() {
        Task<Void> task = mActivityRecognitionClient.requestActivityUpdates(
                20000,
                mPendingIntent);

        task.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Void result) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Successfully requested activity updates",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
        });

        task.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Requesting activity updates failed to start",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
        });
    }

    public void removeActivityUpdatesButtonHandler() {
        Task<Void> task = mActivityRecognitionClient.removeActivityUpdates(
                mPendingIntent);
        task.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Void result) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Removed activity updates successfully!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
        });

        task.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed to remove activity updates!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {


        super.onDestroy();
        //removeActivityUpdatesButtonHandler();
        /**/
    }

    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        public BackgroundDetectedActivitiesService getServerInstance() {
            return BackgroundDetectedActivitiesService.this;
        }
    }
}
```

I have this in my android manifest:

```
<service
    android:name="uk.co.appoly.wheres_my_car.services.ActivityRecognitionService"
    android:exported="false" />

<service android:name="uk.co.appoly.wheres_my_car.services.BackgroundDetectedActivitiesService"></service>
```

(plus correct permissions)

I am starting the service from my MainActivity like so:

```
activityRecognitionClient = ActivityRecognition.getClient(mContext);
        transitionIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, BackgroundDetectedActivitiesService.class);
        startService(transitionIntent);
```

I've been trying to fix this for about a day but to no avail. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what is your `targetSdkVersion` ? and on which OS you are testing?

Comment: targetSdkVersion is 27. Testing on Android 8.1.0